# XSLT copy everything except nodes containing value from variable

Tags: xml, xslt

EDIT:

Thank you for your replies, I understand a bit more now, but can't seem to work it on a more advance case like this input:

```
      <root>
      <output>               
                        <query name="query1">
                            <parameters>
                                <parameter name="id_action">8947</parameter>
                            </parameters>
                            <queryResults/>                     
                        </query>
                        <query name="query1">
                            <parameters>
                                <parameter name="id_action">8943</parameter>
                            </parameters>
                            <queryResults>
                                <record id="1">
                                    <column name="id_action">8943</column>
                                    <column name="Actname">testing</column>
                                </record>
                            </queryResults>
                            <queryErrors/>
                        </query>
                        <query name="query1">
                            <parameters>
                                <parameter name="id_action">1571</parameter>
                            </parameters>
                            <queryResults/>                      
                        </query>                
                </output>       
                <output2>                
                        <query name="query2">
                            <parameters>
                                <parameter name="id">1</parameter>
                            </parameters>
                            <queryResults>
                                <record id="1">
                                     <column name="DepName">West</column>
                                    <column name="id_action">8947</column>
                                </record>
                                <record id="2">
                                    <column name="DepName">West</column>
                                    <column name="id_action">8943</column>
                                </record>
                                <record id="3">
                                    <column name="DepName">East</column>
                                    <column name="id_action">1571</column>
                                </record>
                            </queryResults>                      
                        </query>                    
                </output2>

<root>
```

I want to take the value of **id_action** from the 'query1' which has /queryResults/record (in this case id_action=8943) and copy all the queries with the name "query2" from below except the ones that have column[@name='id_action'] equal to 8943.

Desired output:

```
<root>
    <output2>
       <query name="query2">
                                <parameters>
                                    <parameter name="id">1</parameter>
                                </parameters>
                                <queryResults>
                                    <record id="1">
                                         <column name="DepName">West</column>
                                        <column name="id_action">8947</column>
                                    </record>

                                    <record id="3">
                                        <column name="DepName">East</column>
                                        <column name="id_action">1571</column>
                                    </record>
                                </queryResults>                      
                            </query>        

     </output2>
<root>
```

**EDIT2**:
Note: query1 is a query that gets called multiple times, in the example above 3 times, but only 1 time it has values (when there exists node "record"). So I want to take the id_action only if query1 has 'record' node. Like in this case, 8943 is a valid value. Also, keep in mind, there it the possiblity of having 2 or more possible values for id_action, so I want for each of those values.

Note2: from query2 i want to keep the records that don't have the same values as my values from id_action from above(query1). Note that query2 has record 1,record2,etc.

Basically, for each 'query1' that has queryResults/record, I take the value from that queryResults/record/column[@name='id_action'] and I copy every record from "query2" that doesn't have that value in query2/queryResults/record/column[@name='id_action']

Comment: Please post the expected result of your new example. There is only one query with the name "query2" and it matches the given criteria - so apparently the output should be empty? Also your XML has no root element- this makes it difficult to provide an exact answer.

Comment: michael.hor257k : ty. I've edited the post. Indeed there's only one query 2 but note that it has child nodes "record 1/record 2,etc" i want to compare the values with those columns. Basicaly in my case only record id=1 and 3 should be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***edited in response to your edit***

> I want to take the value of id_action from the 'query1' which has
>   /queryResults/record (in this case id_action=8943) and copy all the
>   queries with the name "query2" from below except the ones that have
>   column[@name='id_action'] equal to 8943.

This is a matter of cross-reference, and as such it's best to handle it with the help of a **[key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)**:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k" match="output/query[queryResults/record]" use="parameters/parameter[@name='id_action']" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- suppress the first output branch -->
<xsl:template match="output"/>

<!-- suppress records that have a matching entry in the other branch -->
<xsl:template match="record[key('k', column[@name='id_action'])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you, i've edited my post to be more exact on where i got stuck

Comment: thank you, works like a charm. for my own knowledge, if let's say i wanted to suppress the records from a 3rd branch that have matching values with the suppresed records from the 'other branch' - as noted in your comment. Is something like this possible in XSL?

Comment: @user3529643 I am sure it's possible, because anything is possible with XSLT (it's a Turing-complete language). However, I am not sure I understand the situation you describe, so I cannot say how this would work. I suggest you post another question.